# rotation from csv file in maxscript

Tags: csv, rotation, 3dsmax, maxscript

Hopefully someone with better maxscript knowledge can help with this.
I have a csv file driving the position of some dummy helpers in 3dsmax. The problem I am having is getting each dummy object to have a local rotation being driven from the csv file. This is a sample from my csv file (actual file has hundreds of points):

```
0,  975.4222,   2181.8731,  0,  267,    360,    75,
```

columns 1 through four name the point and position it to an x y and z coordinate. Columns 5 6 and 7 represent a rotation value for each point around the x y z. This is where I am struggling. If i run my code with the random values then the script fails. If however all the values for column 5 are the same and the values for columns 6 and 7 are also the same then the script will run, but each dummy will have the same rotation (obviously). I know i must be doing something slightly wrong. Any help would be really appreciated. My current code is as follows:

```
    -- open the file as text, read mode
f = openFile "c:\\Testtocsv003c.csv" mode:"rt"

prefabPoint = dummy name:"dummy"

-- if it opened successfully (exists, etc)...
if f != undefined do
(
    while not eof f do
    (
        -- Read a line from the file
        l = readline f
        -- turn that line into an array of strings using commas as delimiters
        lf = filterString l ","
        if (lf[1]!=undefined ) do
        (
            newPoint = instance prefabPoint
            newPoint.name = lf[1]
            x = lf[2] as float -- bracketed number reads column position from text file
            y = lf[3] as float -- bracketed number reads column position from text file
            z = lf[4] as float -- bracketed number reads column position from text file
            xRot = lf[5] as float
            yRot = lf[6] as float
            zRot = lf[7] as float   

            newPoint.pos = [x,y,z] 
            --creates point objects at xyz coordinates from text file. To offset by distance for example change to : [100*x,100*y,100*z]


            rotate newPoint (eulerangles xRot yRot zRot) --rotates point 

        )
    )
    close f
    delete prefabPoint
)
```

Thanks all. Oh and sorry if the formatting is wrong. This is my first post.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

This really should be in a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Anyway, I just ran your code successfully with 500 dummy objects with randomly generated transforms and it ran fine. So it sounds like it might be an issue with memory, possibly related to an open file--I once wrote a script that opened a file to read/write values and I had some strange results when I was doing operations while the file was open. So here's what I would suggest:

1. Read all values from the file into an array and then close the file before instancing your dummy nodes.
2. Wrap your operations and turn off the undo stack. This can sometimes help with memory issues when performing a large number of operations:

```
    with undo off (
        if (lf[1]!=undefined ) do
        (
          -- create instances of dummy nodes here ...
        )
    )
```

Good luck!